# Determine the best k when performing knn

Tags: python, k-nearest-neighbour

I am using the knn means algorithm to distinguish groups. In case on the iris dataset, lets take this example:

```
from sklearn import datasets 
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
```

I understand that I can create different clusters with k. What I am looking for however is a way that can help me to determine what is the best k, so whether 2,3,4 etc... creates the best and most homegenous groups?

Any thoughts on what is considered best practise in this case?

Comment: Training and testing, like K-fold cross validation.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks. Can you elaborate a little on this? And maybe some suggestions for tutorials etc...?